# T-SQL MAX with additional 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like with recods

```
ContactNo   Code       ValidFrom
02822652  B001109953  2019-08-02 00:00:00
02822652  B001109954  2019-08-04 00:00:00
02822653  B001109955  2019-08-08 00:00:00
02822654  B001109956  2019-08-05 00:00:00
02822653  B001109957  2019-08-03 00:00:00
02822654  B001109958  2019-08-06 00:00:00
02822652  B001109959  2019-08-07 00:00:00
```

how to get results like

```
ContactNo   Code       ValidFrom
02822652   B001109959  2019-08-07 00:00:00
02822653   B001109955  2019-08-08 00:00:00
02822654   B001109958  2019-08-06 00:00:00
```

so for each Contact no, get record with maximum of column ValidFrom?

I have tried this

```
select ContactNo, MAX(bb.ValidFrom)as x, Code  
from ICIS_Repl.repl.BankAccount bb 
group by ContactNo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select contactno,code,validfrom from (
select contactno,code,validfrom,
row_number() over (partition by contactno,code,validfrom order by validfrom desc) rn from ICIS_Repl.repl.BankAccount
) t where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT contactno, 
       Max(bb.validfrom)AS x, 
       code 
FROM   icis_repl.repl.bankaccount bb 
GROUP  BY contactno, 
          code
```

You need to group by all fields not aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from ICIS_Repl.repl.BankAccount t
where not exists (
  select 1 from ICIS_Repl.repl.BankAccount
  where ContactNo = t.ContactNo and ValidFrom > t.ValidFrom
)
order by t.ContactNo
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from ICIS_Repl.repl.BankAccount t inner join (
  select ContactNo, max(ValidFrom) MaxValidFrom
  from ICIS_Repl.repl.BankAccount
  group by ContactNo
) g on g.ContactNo = t.ContactNo and g.MaxValidFrom = ValidFrom
order by t.ContactNo
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fab6d6d547e05ed4279a8d253cee2fb9).
Results:

```
> ContactNo | Code       | ValidFrom          
> --------: | :--------- | :------------------
>   2822652 | B001109959 | 07/08/2019 00:00:00
>   2822653 | B001109955 | 08/08/2019 00:00:00
>   2822654 | B001109958 | 06/08/2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: How to do always with 1 record of 1 ContactNo (select that which have highest validFrom)?

Comment: This is what the code does. It returns only 1 row for each ContactNo unless there are 2 rows for the same ContactNo and the same maximum ValidFrom. Is there such a case?

Comment: Check the demo in my answer.

Comment: yes i have many records with the same ContactNo and need to select only 1 with highest ValidFrom